# Create Android service that starts and stops automatically

Tags: android, android-service

I'm pretty puzzled by this whole android service. from my understanding, service is an 'app' which runs on the background, that can start and stop automatically and can communicate with its 'parent' app. or is it?

Here's what I'm actually trying to do:

1. I have an app, which the user can enter the date that he needs to do something
2. the app saves the data (what the user needs to do and the date) inside a sqlite database
3. i need to have a service which runs on the background and twice a day will check the sqlite database if there's a thing that the user needs to do on that day. so the service will only run twice a day. for example, at 6 in the morning, the service will start itself and check the database. then it will close itself. later at 6 in the evening, the service will start itself again and check the database, and close itself.
4. when the service detects that the user needs to do something on the particular date, it will send a notification (like the notification we get from whatsapp or email) to the user, reminding him that he needs to do something
   5) when the user clicks on the notification, it will open the app where the user sets the notification earlier on

Can this be done on Android? If not, what's the closest method to do this? Please direct me to the right tutorial/article or whatsoever to get me started. currently I don't even know what to google.

Comment: Well to start, a service is not an app, its part of your app. It sounds like you want an `IntentService` with an `AlarmManager`

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead,[describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: oook thanks  ... but the alarms documentation in android is talking about  sync adapter too... in my case, which is better? alarm or sync adapter?

Comment: @jurgemaister I don't know where else I could get better answer regarding this than Stack Overflow

Comment: what about bound service with ipc?

Comment: I think that you are looking for a Service that is triggered by a Broadcast Receiver. You could google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is built for running code at certain predetermined times.  You can set a repeating alarm to run every 12hrs starting at the next 6am/6pm.

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 6:00 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 12 hours.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 12, alarmIntent);
```

Then you need to specify a BroadcastReceiver and declare it in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
</receiver>
```

and then handle that message

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startService(...your service intent ...);
    }
}
```

You probably want to use an IntentService to run the DB call.  See http://responsiveandroid.com/2014/12/16/android-services-what-they-are-what-they-are-not.html for how to create an Intent service.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the AlarmManager in android. It's actually a sceduler to run tasks at a particular instance of time ( seconds, days, weeks,...)

So first write your service with the correct functions in it. Check the documentation to see what type of service fits for you.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

```
[Service (Enabled = true)]              
public class AndroidSyncService:Service
{
      public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (global::Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
            {
                        var command = intent.GetStringExtra ("commandType");
                  switch (command) {
                        case "CheckSQL":
                        {
                           RunCheckSqlFunction();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
     }
    private void RunCheckSqlFunction()
    {
     //RUN TASK
    //IF TASK IS FINISHED, STOP THE SERVICE (this.StopSelf ();)

    }

  }
```

This is written in c# (xamarin), but it resembles android allot. The service receives in intent that contains a string "commandType" wich indicates what kind off function must be executed in the service.

Now that you have your service in place, you can register the intent that starts the "CheckSQL" function in the service with the alarmmanager.

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(AndroidSyncService)).PutExtra ("commandType", "CheckSQL");
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService (this, 0, intent, 0);
        var alarm = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService (Context.AlarmService);
        alarm.SetRepeating (AlarmType.Rtc, 0,TimeSpan.FromHours(6).Milliseconds, pendingIntent);
```

With this we tell the alarmmanager to launch the service every 6hours to run your function to check the sql for changes. The code for notifications can be placed int your service, but it's your task to choose how you want to communicate your results to the user. Hope this helps!